# What replaces deprecated batch scene queries in nvidia physx 3.4?

Tags: physics, nvidia, deprecated, physx, batch-query

Apparently, "The batched query feature has been deprecated in PhysX version 3.4". Does anyone know what replaces batch queries going forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are/were not using ps3 which was the purpose of implementing batched query api.  According to nvidia there is no performance benefit to using it if you are not on ps3
https://github.com/NVIDIAGameWorks/PhysX/issues/89

Answer (score 0):

> Batched scene queries are marked as deprecated and will be replaced by new system in future releases.

So you can still use them.

Comment: I know that - my question was if anyone knew what replaces them.